# module.js:327 Error: Cannot find module 'express'

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I am new in a nodejs and when I run any file in command prompt like:-

C:\demoData>node demo.js

I get error li9ke this

```
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\demoData\shahzad.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
```

I did R&D and get the solution

npm install express

And my Problem has solved using this. But Why I required this I have already express folder globally.this path

```
C:\Users\broswire\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules;
```

I want to use this node_modules, I don't want locally node_modules.

Comment: Is express installed globally? Does `C:\Users\broswire\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express` exist?

Comment: @user1280859: yes this folder exist

Comment: Check answer from this issue https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3865 . And it's realy bad practice to install libs like express globally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node encourages using locally installed modules. Generally, using modules installed with `npm install --global` or `npm install -g` should be reserved for cli tools and things used systemwide. So to use `express` in a project, it is recommended to `npm install express` in that directory. It is also useful to add a `package.json` file to save the versions of your dependencies. Then you can just navigate to your project and run `npm install` and it will install the required dependencies.